# Rerun Task When It Fails in VSCode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, freezed, build-runner

I make an Android app in Flutter and I use `build_runner` to generate code, especially [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) codes.

My `tasks.json` is as below:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "flutter",
            "command": "flutter",
            "args": [
                "pub",
                "run",
                "build_runner",
                "watch",
                "--delete-conflicting-outputs"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$dart-build_runner"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "label": "flutter: flutter pub run build_runner watch",
            "detail": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem with `build_runner` is that it exits when I change branch with git saying:

```
[SEVERE] Terminating builds due to package graph update, please restart the build.
[INFO] Terminating. No further builds will be scheduled

[INFO] Builds finished. Safe to exit
```

While this is mainly a problem with this tooling and it rightfully exits due to changes in dependencies, I wonder if there's a way to rerun the task even if it fails in VSCode.

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

- KDE Neon 5.24 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) (if relevant)
- VSCode 1.65.2

`flutter doctor -v` output (if relevant):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.3, on KDE neon User - 5.24 5.13.0-37-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.10.3 at /home/erayerdin/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 7e9793dee1 (4 weeks ago), 2022-03-02 11:23:12 -0600
    • Engine revision bd539267b4
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /opt/sdks/android/
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/119/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = /snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code
    • VS Code at /snap/code/current
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.84

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```